Building a simple Interface-Implementation with Code generation (Elab Monad with Elaboration Reflection) in Idris2
my simple problem is, that i want to build an Interface implementation or a couple of them when giving a list of Strings as Input in a function thats using the Elab () Monad to automatically generate Interfaces for every String in the following way:
module LanguageReflect

import Data.List1
import Language.Reflection
import Language.Reflection.Pretty
import Language.Reflection.Syntax
import Language.Reflection.Syntax.Ops
import Language.Reflection.Util
import Data.Vect.Quantifiers

%language ElabReflection


locTyImpl : (locName : String) -> List Decl
locTyImpl locName = 
    let functionName    = UN . Basic $ "KnownLocTy_" ++ locName
        location = var "fromString" .$ primVal (Str locName)

        clause          = (var "toLoc") .$ implicitTrue .= location

    in [interfaceHint Public functionName (var "KnownLocTy" .$ location),
        def functionName [clause]]


mkLocImpl : String -> Elab () 
mkLocImpl locName = declare $ locTyImpl locName

My normal Interface for "Known" Strings so I can fetch them from a Location Type:
interface KnownLocTy l where
    toLoc : LocTy l -> String

The outcome I expect when my Code would work:
KnownLocTy "Consti" where
  toLoc _ = "Consti"

It is not even complex Metaprogramming but sadly I dont know why it does not work properly, my guess is that var "fromString" .$ primVal (Str locName) as the location in form of a constant on Type level in my implementation-header is not defined in the right way.
The Compiler Error when it is type-checking %runElab (mkLocImpl "Consti") is:

Error during reflection: While processing left hand side of KnownLocTy_Consti. Dot pattern not valid here (unknown type) ($resolved7674 _)

Any Help is much appreciated and I give more context when needed.
Cheers
Weasel
